# Target device api level(API 1) too low for Instant run Android Studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have ZTE Axon 7 with android 7.1.1

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {       
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }
}
```

But I cant do "Instant Run" - in menu Run I see
Apply changes: Target device API level (API1) too low to Instant Run

Where did API1 come from?

PS IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.6 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-182.5107.16, built on November 6, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b22 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 7 6.1

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I reboot computer and restart Idea, and after that Instant Run works fine